# Is it possible for lager to output 2 different log file for different application?

Tags: erlang, lager

I want to write a monitoring application (erlang application). The monitored application and my monitoring application are not both written in erlang and run in the same vm.

Now the log is mixed, and I consider to use disk_log in monitoring application.

My question is that is it possible for both applications use lager and lager output log into different file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to log specific messages to separate files using lager, but the common log files like info.log would have those messages as well. If that's fine with you take a look at tracing: https://github.com/basho/lager/blob/master/README.md#tracing

Comment: Thank you. Mixed in info.log is not situation what I wanted. But this is lager restriction.